# Python: deleting characters from the list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
s = ['www.abc.com/1/2/3', 'www.xyz.com/3/4/5', 'www.try.com/6/7/5']
```

I would like to modify the list to get following result:

```
s = ['www.abc.com', 'www.xyz.com', 'www.try.com']
```

i.e. remove "/" and every character after "/" from each string in the list.

Comment: `s = [x.split('/')[0] for x in s]`

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: What about `'http://www.example.com'`?

Comment: What about `'www.example.com:80/1/2/3'`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: There are really two questions here: 1) how to process every item in a list, and 2) how to extract the hostname from a URL string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split each string according to the `/` character. E.g.:

```
result = [x.split('/', 1)[0] for x in s]
```

Comment: Or even `x.split('/', 1)[0]` because you don't really need to split on _all_ the slashes.

Comment: Based on the nature of the question, I bet the OP needs a clue such as "Use list comprehensions and the string split() method" for this answer to be intelligible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over long lists probably regex would be more efficient:

```
import re
s = ['www.abc.com/1/2/3', 'www.xyz.com/3/4/5', 'www.try.com/6/7/5']
result=[re.sub('/*','',i) for i in s]
```